# SVG close (X) image appears as blank?

Tags: svg

Why does my SVG image of `X` appears blank?

```html
<svg fill="#ffffff" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"/>
  <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG isn't blank, it's white.

You've set the fill of the entire SVG to `#ffffff`. Simply update the fill with the desired color to reveal the 'X' against a white background.

I've also added a closing SVG tag in the example which I assume was simply a copy/paste mistake.

```html
<svg fill="#ff0000" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```